Gigabit internet slows down when switch is introduced
I have a gigabit internet connection and it works absolutely fine when the Ethernet is connected directly into the PC's Lan Port.
Now when I try to put in a switch (4 port gigabit switch), the speed i get on both PCs is 93-94mbps
I have tried :-

Six different switches - Current switch Netgear GS305
6 different patch cables (switch to PCs)
what else do i need to do? its mind boggling as both the PCs work when connected directly, giving gigabit speeds.
thanks for your help!
best wishes
Sam

So to comment on all the questions asked... the switch is a netgear GS305, and just to be sure i have swapped it with a tplink TL-SG105S - no change! cable changed several times - 4 pairs cables used cat6 from reputed brands!, network connected at 1 gigabit (shows on adapter), no other device is connected (for now)

What is the type and vendor of your switch? Please add that info with an edit to the question. And maybe the switch is defect?!?

94.3 Mbps is the max thruput after overhead for TCP/IPv4 over 100BASE-T. It's a telltale sign that you're falling back to 100Mbit Ethernet instead of gigabit. Did you buy a bunch of ripoff switches or cables from wish.com? Did you verify the cable pinouts on both ends of each cable?

What does the connection handshake at ? 1gbit or 100mbit ? How are you measuring the speed ?

Are there other devices connected? If so, one could be causing the switch to limit speed.

You're not telling us anything about your upstream connection. Is there a router? Have you checked that router?
So my best guess: Are you sure your router is connecting to the switch at 1 Gb/s ? It is possible this router doesn't like being connected to a switch in stead of a PC.
Try replacing the cable between router and switch with a cross-cable instead of a regular LAN cable. This sometimes helps.
(In theory using a cross or straight cable shouldn't make any difference for Gigabit as that is supposed to be auto-mdix, but in practise... There are a lot of badly designed devices out there for which it does make a difference.)

its a leased line, i have exactly the same setup in another room with switch and its all giving out 1 gig output (on a switch, same make and model)
whereas downstairs the same setup is failing to give 1 gig..
